# Made a variable in heading, not showing up when called in body

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code in heading:

```
  <script>
    var seconds = 0;
    var clockId;

    function runClock {
        seconds++;
    }
  </script>
```

Later in the document I set the value equal to seconds, a variable I made in the header.

```
    <aside>
        <script>
        document.write('<input name="quizclock" id="quizclock" value="' + seconds + '" />');
        </script>
        <input id="start" type="button" value="Start Quiz" />
        <input id="stop" type="button" value="Submit Answers" />

     </aside>
```

When I run the page it doesn't work, although it does work if I make the variable in the body, but how come it won't understand the variables I make in the heading?

EDIT: Seems it was due to not having () with the function.

Comment: please delete the question

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition contains syntax error. The whole block is not executing.

'Should have brackets after the function name.

Please, observe Dev Tools - Console before breaking your head over such things.

And yes, `var seconds` is visible across the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write('<input name="quizclock" id="quizclock" value="' + seconds + '" />');
```

should be escaped as:

```
document.write('<input name=\"quizclock\" id=\"quizclock\" value="\" + seconds + "\" />');
```